# How do I output a variable changed in a void method in Java

Tags: java

According to an exercise for school I am supposed to println the int variable 'aantalWoorden' and the Arraylist 'woorden' after they are updated in the 'woordenNaarLijst' method. But whenever I do that, I get the values from the default constructor (Because they are updated inside a method). The method is supposed to be void, so I can't return the values. How do I get the values of the int and array as they are defined in the 'woordenNaarLijst' method without changing the method itself.

I am sorry if this is a easy question or if I am doing something wrong, but I am relatively new to programming.

```
public class AnalyseZin {
    private String zin;
    int aantalWoorden;
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> woorden;

    public AnalyseZin() {
        woorden = new ArrayList<>();
        aantalWoorden = 0;
    }

    public int getIndex(int i) {
        char c;
        for (; i < zin.length(); i++) {
            c = zin.charAt(i);
            if (c == '\n' || c == '.' || c == ',' || c == ' ')
                return i;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public String getWoord() {
        i2 = getIndex(i1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (; i1 < i2; i1++) {
            sb.append(zin.charAt(i1));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void woordenNaarLijst() {
        String s;
        while (true) {
            s = getWoord();
            if (s.length()==0) break;
            woorden.add(s);
            aantalWoorden++;
        }
    }       
}
```

I left out irrelevant pieces of code, the code does work at my end.

Comment: You are accessing the class members `woorden` and `aantalWoorden` in the method `woordenNaarLijst`. Any changes made in the method will be reflected outside. Please check `if (s.length()==0) break;` is stopping the execution before the update happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you just want to get the values of aantalWoorden and woorden regardless if it has been properly updated or not, you might want to create getters for those.

Example:

```
// Additional getter methods in AnalyseZin

public int getAantalWoorden(){
    return aantalWoorden;
}

public ArrayList<String> getWoorden(){
    return woorden;
}
```

So if you create the AnalyseZin object you can do this:

```
// create variables for the container of values from the AnalyseZin
int newIntVal = 0;
ArrayList<String> newListVal = new ArrayList<String>();

// create instance of the object
AnalyseZin test = new AnalyseZin();
// call woordenNaarLijst method to update the woorden and aantalWoorden
test.woordenNaarLijst();

// pass values from AnalyseZin
newIntVal = test.getAantalWoorden
newListVal = test.getWoorden();

// print out int values
System.out.println("new int value = " + Integer.toString(newIntVal));
// print out list contents
for (String item : newListVal){
    System.out.println("item from list = " + item);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I didn't use the container part. Is this always required when you need to print out values from another class?

Comment: @Baithoven No you don't have to use containers. You can use it directly to print out the values. I just want to make it easier to read. :) Thanks for accepting my answer. :)